# how to exclude certain input fields when injecting form object into FormData constructor?

Tags: javascript

```
  $('#rewardForm').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
        var formData = new FormData($('input[name!="files[]"]', $(this)[0]))
        console.log(formData);;
  })
```

I would like to exclude the input field with name equals to "files[]". And then inject the form object into FormData(). What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider using [`FormData.delete()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/delete)

This way you can remove specified fields from your `formData` object.

In your example, you could use: `formData.delete('files');`

Try running the snippet below or see this **[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/oGbGJq)**

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $("#rewardForm").submit(e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($("#rewardForm")[0]);

    // add fields here that you want to remove
    formData.delete('files');
    formData.delete('last_name');

    // Display the key/value pairs (this is how you debug a formData object)
    for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(`name: ${pair[0]}, value: ${pair[1]}`);
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.container {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
}

.form-control {
  margin: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='container'>
  <h3>Form with removed fields</h3>
  <form action="#" id="rewardForm">
    <input type="text" placeholder='First Name' class='form-control' name='first_name'>
    <input type="text" placeholder='Last Name' class='form-control' name='last_name' />
    <input type="text" placeholder='Profession' class='form-control' name='profession' />
    <input type="file" class='form-control' name='files' />
    <input type="submit" class='form-control btn btn-success' />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply the `.not()` selector to remove the unwanted inputs with `name="files[]"` from your original selection and use the result as the argument in your FormData() constructor:

```
$('input',this).not('[name="files[]"]')
```

(`this` is equivalent with `$(this)[0]`.)

Edit:
Since the FormData() constructor expects a `<form>` object you can generate that by doing

```
$('<form>').append($('input',this).not('[name="files[]"]'))[0]
```

You will have to use this as argument in your FormData() constructor.

Comment: Came across this trying to fix uploads for IE in a custom drag/drop file upload implementation. Works well, but I would suggest amending the second example to `$('<form>').append($('input',this).not('[name="files[]"]').clone())[0]` so the original input isn't moved to a throwaway form, instead a new one is created.